# How do I get PHP to connect automatically to GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, php

How do I get PHP to connect automatically to GeoServer? So I do not need to go into GeoServer manually by entering the username and password.
And how to queries on PostGIS can directly publish and request layer from GeoServer?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the GeoServer REST API. With it, you can create and retrieve workspaces, featuretypes/layers, intereact with PostGIS, etc, from within your PHP application. Refer to the [REST documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/restconfig/rest-config-api.html) and [PHP REST Examples](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/restconfig/rest-config-examples/rest-config-examples-php.html) for details.